# How do I create and save a simple text file to my iCloud Drive Documents folder in Swift?

Tags: swift, icloud

I have built a very simple iOS app which should create a sample text file called `test.txt` in my Documents folder on my iCloud Drive but when I run the app on an iPhone 12 Pro simulator and check my iCloud Drive on my mac it isn't there.

Here is my Capabilities Tab;

[Capabilities tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJhyq.png)

Here is my Info.plist file;

[Info.plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxtad.png)

Here is my ViewController code;

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  InfoPill
//
//  Created by Stephen Learmonth on 01/08/2022.
//

import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let driveURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
        if driveURL != nil {
            print("iCloud available")
            let fileURL = driveURL!.appendingPathComponent("test.txt")
            try? "Hello world".data(using: .utf8)?.write(to: fileURL)
            
        } else {
            print("iCloud not available")
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

my code prints `iCloud available`

Comment: Does the file exist on the Simulator?

Comment: No, I have checked on the simulator, on my macBook pro and on a real device.

Comment: Never write `try?`. You're just throwing away the possible answer to your own question, which is silly. Use a real `do/catch` and print out the error so you know if there was one and what it was.

Comment: I tried a do-catch block around the try? statement but Xcode said the catch block was unreachable.

Comment: If you use do/catch swap the `try?` for `try`

Comment: Regarding your question did you set the privacy keys correctly? See -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/72832906/6950415

Comment: changed try? to try - still no sample file.

Comment: If you mean the Supports Document Browser then yes - still no sample file written.

Comment: Get rid of the `try` while debugging. Are any errors or exceptions thrown?

Comment: No errors, no exceptions.